# Creating adjacency matrix with dirty dataset

Tags: r, matrix, data-cleaning, adjacency-matrix

This is the second time I am posting this question having deleted the first due to lack of reproducibility.

I referenced previously answered questions (Creating Adjacency Matrix and Social Network Graph, Creating adjacency matrix from raw data for centrality, Clean one column from long and big data set) but am struggling between the data cleaning and then creating the matrix.

Here is part of the df I am working from -

```
Species     Association              
1 RC          SKS/BW                   
2 BW          Sykes, rc                
3 SKS         Babo/bw                  
4 RC          baboon, mangabey         
5 Mang        red colobus, bw, sykes   
6 SKS         babo/red duiker
```

I am working on creating a simple social network matrix to answer "who is associating with whom at what frequency".

To clean the data I have selected the needed columns (Species and Association) and created a column to indicate the specific site where this data was collected

```
df.clean <-  mutate(df, Association=fct_collapse(Association, 
  BW=c("SKS/BW" ,"Babo/bw", "red colobus, bw, sykes"), 
  RC=c("Sykes, rc" ,"red colobus, bw, sykes"), 
  SKS=c("SKS/BW", "Sykes, rc", "red colobus, bw, sykes"), 
  Mang=c("baboon, mangabey"), 
  BABO=c("Babo/bw", "baboon, mangabey", "babo/red duiker"), 
  RD=c("babo/red duiker")) %>% 
select(Species, Association) %>% 
add_column(Site = "Protected") %>% 
filter(Species!= "RD", Association!= "RD") %>% 
mutate(Species = factor(as.character(Species)))
```

However, when I look at the column "Association" after this step, I am only seeing one species value (i.e. bw instead of bw,rc) in the entire column.

I assume I have buggered up my dataset by using the 'fct_collapse()' function while cleaning? I am looking for an output dataframe like this -

```
Species     Association              Site
1 RC          SKS, BW                  Protected
2 BW          SKS, RC                  Protected
3 SKS         BABO, BW                 Protected
4 RC          BABO, Mang               Protected
5 Mang        RC, BW, SKS              Protected
6 SKS         BABO                     Protected
```

This brings me to my first question - what's the best way to clean dirty data like this while retaining the multiple values of information in the column? I am trying to create a dataframe like the above example assuming I will then need to code both the species and association column to numeric values to create my matrix. Will this work as written, or do I need to extract data from the column and create new columns?

I'm relatively new to r, so please let me know if I'm not making any sense. Any advice is greatly appreciated, and I apologize if there's any confusion.

Upon running code from the kind commenter, I am running into coding issues with the association column. Everything runs great, except, there are "NA"s for association anytime there was a "R/c monkeys" or "B/W colobus", essentially anytime there was a '/' in the naming of the association. Here

troubleshooting dput sample dataframe

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("BABO", "BW", "Mang", "RC", "SKS"
), class = "factor"), Association = c("r/c monkeys", "b/w colobus", 
"b/w colobus/R/c monkeys", "sykes/R/c monkeys", "sykes/b/w colobus", 
".", ".", ".", "r/c monkeys", "sykes monkeys"), year = c(12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Dput output looks like -

```
Species    Association                  Year
<fctr>     <chr>                        <dbl>
BW         r/c monkeys                  12
RC         b/w colobus                  12
SKS        b/w colobus/R/c monkeys      12
BW         sykes/R/c monkeys            12
RC         sykes/b/w colobus            12
BABO       .                            12
SKS        .                            12
RC         .                            12
SKS        r/c monkeys                  12
RC         sykes monkeys                12
```

Ideal dput output -

```
Species    Association                  Year
<fctr>     <chr>                        <dbl>
BW         RC                           12
RC         BW                           12
SKS        BW, RC                       12
BW         SKS, RC                      12
RC         SKS, BW                      12
BABO       NA                           12
SKS        NA                           12
RC         NA                           12
SKS        RC                           12
RC         SKS                          12
```

Comment: My general advice would be to have your goal be a data frame with one row per adjacency. Currently you have one row per Species, and the first row (for example) implies 2 adjacencies. You can maybe use the `tidyr` function `separate_rows` to create more rows so that you have one row per adjacency, and then I would imagine making the adjacency matrix would follow naturally from one of the questions you link.

Comment: @akrun I am trying to figure out the dput. I didn't use it to input my data here. I just simplified my dataframe and manually wrote it out.

Comment: It is easier to get the dput output you can use `dput(head(df))` it prints the structure.  Reason is to make the example reproducible in case your columns are strings or list

Comment: @gregorthomas This make sense, but with a dataframe with thousands of rows, how would I separate my association values with code?

Comment: @gregorthomas Okay, thank you for calling that to my attention. I am going to work on my dataset with all of the current suggestions before adding new info/edits. I really appreciate you taking the time to look at my issues!

Comment: Upon looking more, I think I would start by using `separate_rows()` to get each indiividual associated species on its own line (much like what Jay's answer does), **then** use `fct_collapse` to collapse the variant spellings of individual species into the canonical form you want to use. Generally it's hard to work with data items concatenated together in the same string, and `fct_collapse` is not made to work with data like that, so splitting/separating makes sense as the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `strsplit()` and `toString()`. Just use a *regular expression* like `'(?<=\\w{2})\\/|,\\s'` that covers all cases. Enjoy the [playground](https://regex101.com/)<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>*Note that only single escapes `\` are required there, while double escapes `\\` are required in R.</sup>

```
regex <- '(?<=\\w{2})\\/|,\\s'
```

To fix the different name versions, we first use `toupper()` which already takes away some of the pain. Then use a `dict`ionary that you neatly can paste together in your script using `read.table()`,

```
dict <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
            from  to
             "."  .
   "B/W COLOBUS"  BW
          "BABO"  BABO
        "BABOON"  BABO
            "BW"  BW
      "MANGABEY"  MANG
   "R/C MONKEYS"  RC
            "RC"  RC
   "RED COLOBUS"  COLO
    "RED DUIKER"  DUIK
           "SKS"  SKS
         "SYKES"  SKS
 "SYKES MONKEYS"  SKS
')
```

where you might find that one helpful:

```
spf <- '"%s"'
# spf <- '%s'  ## for the playground (see above)

data.frame(from=
             sprintf(spf, 
                     sort(unique(unlist(
                       strsplit(toupper(dat$Association), regex, perl=TRUE)
                     )))
             )
) |> print(row.names=FALSE)
```

Then `strsplit`, use the dictionary to replace names, and clean it a little:

```
res <- strsplit(toupper(dat$Association), regex, perl=TRUE) |>
  lapply(\(x) dict[match(x, dict$from), ]$to) |>
  sapply(toString) |>
  {\(.) replace(., . == ".", NA)}() |>
  data.frame('Protected', as.factor(toupper(dat$Species)), dat$year) |>
  setNames(c('association', 'site', 'species', 'year')) |>
  subset(select=c(3, 1, 2, 4))

res
#    species   association      site year
# 1       RC       SKS, BW Protected   NA
# 2       BW       SKS, RC Protected   NA
# 3      SKS      BABO, BW Protected   NA
# 4       RC    BABO, MANG Protected   NA
# 5     MANG COLO, BW, SKS Protected   NA
# 6      SKS    BABO, DUIK Protected   NA
# 7       BW            RC Protected   12
# 8       RC            BW Protected   12
# 9      SKS        BW, RC Protected   12
# 10      BW       SKS, RC Protected   12
# 11      RC       SKS, BW Protected   12
# 12    BABO          <NA> Protected   12
# 13     SKS          <NA> Protected   12
# 14      RC          <NA> Protected   12
# 15     SKS            RC Protected   12
# 16      RC           SKS Protected   12
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Species = c("RC", "BW", "SKS", "RC", "Mang", "SKS", 
"BW", "RC", "SKS", "BW", "RC", "BABO", "SKS", "RC", "SKS", "RC"
), Association = c("SKS/BW", "Sykes, rc", "Babo/bw", "baboon, mangabey", 
"red colobus, bw, sykes", "babo/red duiker", "r/c monkeys", "b/w colobus", 
"b/w colobus/R/c monkeys", "sykes/R/c monkeys", "sykes/b/w colobus", 
".", ".", ".", "r/c monkeys", "sykes monkeys"), year = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "11", "21", "31", "41", "51", "61", 
"7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you for the start on the cleaning! This standardizes the punctuation, but it does not standardize the species names. Sykes is the same as SKS is the same as sykes; babo is the same as baboon is the same as Babo.

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree I see! You could use a dictionary, which needs to be created manually, but that's easy using `read.table()`, please see update.

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you! I will get to work with the entire dataframe and if I have questions will create new posts. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help, @MarneeRoundtree, please consider to [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if this is closed.

Comment: I am running into an error with `lapply(\(x) dict[match(x, dict$from), ]$to)` part of the code. However, I have an older mac so am in the process of downloading the newest version of everything with packages on a different computer. I hope this will resolve the issue. Until this, if you don't mind, I will keep it open (should be finished by tomorrow).

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree Most importantly you will need R >= 4.1 because of the `|>` pipes and `\(x)` function notation.

Comment: Great news, it works with the new version! Not so great news, the coding works beautifully until you get towards the end of the dataset. At that point, it's like the code just stopped working and all the association data goes back to the original (i.e. "sykes monkeys", "b/w colobus", "r/c colobus".

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree Impressive work! Can you provide such a (not) working _minimal_ example as edit to your question?

Comment: Working on it now! Would it be better to start a new question or edit the current one?

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree Let's try here first, maybe the code just needs to be adapted a litle.

Comment: Okay, great! I just uploaded some additional information. So it appears the code is running any species with a '/' in the name as an NA instead of the species. I have in the dictionary "R/c monkeys" to "RC", but it's not reading that correctly. Any ideas? I've tried rearranging your code with the sapply function first, but as I'm sure you already know, that didn't work.

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree Could you `dput` a whole mini sample data frame like you did the first time?

Comment: Okay, should be good to go now! I added both the dput output, a copy of the output, and then what I'm looking for for an output. Let me know what else I can help with. Thank you again!

Comment: @MarneeRoundtree Please see updated answer.

Comment: I had some issues with my df, but after some troubleshooting, got it. You did it!! Thank you so unbelievably much. You are an absolute wizard!

Comment: I have a regex question about this dataset if you're interested. No pressure at all, and thank you again for all your help!(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71411747/regex-comma-use-in-data-cleaning-with-r)